# Execute functions in order in Android

Tags: android, function, android-intent

I'm trying to make program with functions.

Code is so simple, but I'm struggling with basic grammar in java.

```
OnClickListener voiceListener = new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) { 
              FA();//I want FB is operated after FA and onActivityResult are finished..
              FB(); 
            }
        };


private void FA(){...startActivityForResult(intent,check);  
        }
private void FB(){}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
}
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

//
The problem is, when I click the button, FA and FB are operating together and seems like it FA, FB 
What I wanted to see was, after FA is performed( intent is passed), the program gets into onActivityResult and results are applied to FB. 
Where should I touch for doing this? What am I going to do? 
I'm expecting to seeing opinions! :)

Comment: Put  FB(); in onActivityResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the operations of FB() method inside the onActivityResult method, just like this

```
OnClickListener voiceListener = new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) { 
              FA();//I want FB is operated after FA and onActivityResult are finished..
              //Don't call FB over here
            }
        };

//FA method defined here which startActivityForResult
private void FA(){...startActivityForResult(intent,check);  
        }

//FB method defined here    
private void FB(){}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            //Call FB over here
            FB(); 
}
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Still got doubts? Comment below.

Comment: Clearly Understand! Thanks and it works!! Is it common that following function like FB() should be in onActivityResult? What if I want to repeat FA() again? repeated again again => FA->onActivityresult->FB->FA->onactivityResult->fB->...

Comment: Its not a common practice. In you case as you wanted it to be executed once your results is returned, FB() has to be put in `onActivityResult()`. If you want FA() to execute I would recommend you can initiate by clicking the view again, as putting that in the `onActivityResult` will make it a continuous loop.